# Why using "this" in JavaScript is "like pair programming with Abbott and Costello"?

Tags: programming, pop-culture

I'm aware that this question requires, in addition to some cultural context about Abbott and Costello, good expertise on quality JavaScript or OO coding. But I'm confident that there are plenty of people here with both knowledges.

From [JSLint Help on `this`](https://www.jslint.com/help.html#this):

> Having `this` in the language makes it harder to talk about the
>   language. It is like pair programming with Abbott and Costello.

What should I know about Abbott and Costello to understand what [Douglas Crockford](https://www.google.com/search?q=Douglas+Crockford) means? (Or have a hint.)

Comment: I would disagree that having `this` makes it harder to talk about the language.

Comment: @HotLicks Examining the video provided by bogle, Crockford seems to mean that having a keyword in your _programming_ language which is a common word in your _natural_ language makes harder to talk about the _programming_ language. He could have explained himself better.

Comment: The Q has everything to do with Abbott and Costello, and the function of "this" in programming. If you know both, you know the answer. Else ask on [programmers.se]

Comment: What?  I don't know.

Comment: I am Spaniard so I didn't know about "Who's on first?" routine more than you people out of Spain probably know Miguel Gila's. Crockford's "explanation" left me baffled and so my question. Knowing that routine to understand what even means DC is one question (probably suitable for English SE) and discussing the convenience of DC's ban in JSLint recommendation is another (definitely more suitable for SO or Software Engineering). Maybe I ask it, because DC states in the very video that bogle links "`this` is the key to prototypal inheritance" but in JSLint is categorical: "Avoid using `this`" So?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv - You mean like `begin`, `end`, `try`, `catch`, `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `switch`, et al?

Comment: @HotLicks I was just trying to make a little sense of these DC's sentences, which belongs to here. Discussing his good sense in `this` topic, `if` he's being rational here or `if` `this` is more a dislike or grudge to the point to advise all JS coders on Earth to avoid using `this` and relinquish prototypal inheritance for good belongs to SO or the like. (To be continued; too long by 10 characters.)

Comment: I'll grant DC that `this` keyword is especially poorly chosen but, hey, suggest an alternative and stop bitching around. My guess is he really doesn't want `this` to be changed because it provides him `with` good laughs every time he speaks on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can only be a reference to the ['Who's on first?'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F) routine.

He just means to point out the awkwardness of discussing something named 'this'.  For example, one programmer might ask another 'what *this* are you talking about, this this or that this?'.

Comment: Mmm, maybe but if the only problem is that two programmers cannot talk clearly one to the other, I don't see clear why this is bad programming. It's just the name piss him off? There was a reason to invent `this`. A `this` by another name would be avoidable as this (`this`) or would Crockford be content if the name was another?

Comment: I believe it is simply the name.  I'm not sure if he has ever suggested a different name for the parameter.  He elaborates on the topic in the following talk. https://youtu.be/ya4UHuXNygM?t=699

Comment: "He elaborates on the topic . . ." Do you mean on `this` topic? :)